# Divide data in one row with other row using sql without pivots

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is in the following format.

```
Type   R1   R2  R3
------------------
A      10   14  16
B      2    2   4 
C      0    0   0
```

I want to divide A by B and place the value in R1,R2,R3 respectively.

```
Type   R1   R2  R3
------------------    
A      10   14  16
B      2    2   4 
C      5    7   4
```

Please suggest. The columns R1,R2,R3 are dynamic

Comment: Hi, please read the FAQ to understand what this forum is about: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and also feel free to read http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 8):

This should do the trick. I think you'll be able to do the rest by yourself.

```
SELECT
    (t0.R1 / t1.R1) AS R1,
    (t0.R2 / t1.R2) AS R2,
    (t0.R3 / t1.R3) AS R3
FROM    
    test t0
LEFT JOIN
    test t1
ON
    t1.type = 'B'
WHERE
    t0.type = 'A';
```